# Will the id Software game RAGE be placed in the Software Centre Shop?

Tags: software-center, games

Rage will come in 2011 and it would be nice to have it in the Ubuntu Software Centre Shop! It is based on idTech 5 and uses OpenGL. There is just a need of coorparating with id Software.

Comment: I think this question will better place to the Id Software support forum.

Answer (score 2):

How do you expect anybody here to be able to answer this with any degree of certainty?

If id want to release a Linux version (still not confirmed) and want to sell it through the Software Centre and Canonical are happy to support a 5-8gig game and they can come to an arrangement on the distribution fees, then sure, it could be there.